# ¿Se puede hacer un commit en una sola linea para los archivos nuevos (Untracked) en git?

Tags: git

La idea es en una sola linea hacer `commit` a los archivos nuevos, es decir los archivos `Untracked`, así como los cambios `Unstaged` en los archivos a los que ya se les hace seguimiento.

#### Ejemplo:

Se tienen 2 archivos:

1. **level-4.md**
2. **text.txt**

De los cuales **level-4.md** se le está haciendo seguimiento ya, y **text.txt** es un archivo recién creado al que no se le ha hecho ningún seguimiento.

Luego, se realizan cambios a ambos archivos, y lo que se desea es tener en una sola línea un `commit` que confirme todos los cambios en el repositorio.

#### Nota:

Se desea algo como:

```
git commit -am "Mensaje del commit"
```

Solo que esta forma, solo considera los cambios hechos en los archivos a los que se les está haciendo seguimiento, es decir, guarda los cambios en **level-4.md** e ignora los hechos en **text.txt**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar dos comandos en una sola línea de la siguiente manera:

```
git add -A && git commit -m "Tu mensaje"
```

El primero agrega todos los archivos *untracked* y el segundo hace el *commit*.